# How to debug direct_mail under TYPO3 6.2

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have made my first TYPO3 4.5>6.2 Update and it seems quite fine.

I have an issue with direct_mail though I didn't find mentioned anywhere.

The direct_mail 4.0 module stays completely empty, no matter which module I choose.
There are no php errors thrown.
The Sysfolders that are to be used by direct_mail are configured with "Use as Container > Contains Plugin".

How can I debug this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the install tool and enable the Development-Preset. After enabling, the error messages should appear. I also updated a direct_mail installation from a 4.4 TYPO3 to 6.2 a while ago and got it working.

Comment: I did this - thanks for the hint! But no, still blank. Did you experience similar issues?

Comment: Have you updated the extension to the latest version? I guess there is no other way. Version > 4.0 is needed.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately yes